# Is their any contradictory case for this statement?

Tags: graph-theory, theorem-proving, theorem

I say: If I make a directed graph G with every vertex having exactly one outdegree and any number of indegree then

1) The graph can have at most 1 cycle 
2) The graph G is connected

If not true please provide a counterexample too.

If true can you suggest any more properties of graph G which can be used for eliminating the cycle? ( note: new vertex joins and leaves dynamically)

I am trying to make a decentralised mesh formation algorithm for wireless networks using ESP32 modules. 
Every directed outgoing edge is an STA (Station) connecting AP (Access Point)
Every vertex is a node

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. But you mean [weakly connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073602/534447), not connected. Here's a proof:

1. Let `G=(V,E)` be a directed graph and suppose `G` is weakly connected and has at least two cycles;
2. Let `A`⊂`V` be the set of vertices in one cycle and `B`⊂`V` is the set of vertices a second cycle. The out-degree of each vertex in both `A` and `B` is at least one and *may* be exactly one;
3. In order for any vertex from `A` to reach any vertex in `B`, then an edge from `A` to `B` is required. Therefore, at least one vertex from `A` must have out-degree 2.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned above it's a weakly connected graph. Actually, I was referring to the network G thus formed as a connected graph since every edge is a connection between STA and an AP which is a bidirectional data path. I greatly appreciate suggestions on how to remove the cycle (if it occurs in a dynamic environment )? @giusti

Comment: I'm not sure. If you have a cycle, then to remove it you must either remove one vertex or one edge. If you remove an edge and want the graph to remain weakly connected, you can insert the edge's transpose. But I don't know if that makes sense, given your graph comes from a network configuration.

Comment: Removing node is not possible. I was also thinking about removing an edge ( stop a STA from connecting to an AP) but the real challenge is in devicing an algorithm that can prevent these cycles from connecting. I have something in mind, I will let you know if it work out well. Thank you for your precious suggestions.